# Mounting Shared Network Volume Docker Compose (Windows host / Linux Container)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume, docker-for-windows

I'm trying to mount a volume in docker-compose between my Windows host and linux container:

```yaml
version: '3'

volumes:
  my_vol:
    driver_opts:
      type: cifs
      o: "addr=xxx.xx.com,username=<USER>,password=<PWD>"
      device: "//xxx.xx.com/<MY_FOLDER>"

services:
  cont:
    container_name: Cont
    privileged: true
    build: .
    volumes:
     - my_vol:/mnt/my_vol
    command: tail -f /dev/null
```

Now I've tried a couple of different volumes to mount but I either get this error:

```
Error response from daemon: failed to mount local volume: mount
//xxx.xx.com/<MY_FOLDER>:/var/lib/docker/volumes/cont_my_vol/_data, data:
addr=XXX.XXX.X.XXX, username=<USER>, password=<PWD>: no such file or directory
```

or this one:

```
Error response from daemon: failed to copy file info for
/var/lib/docker/volumes/cont_my_vol/ data: failed to utime
/var/lib/docker/volumes/cont_my_vol/_data: permission denied.
```

It seems to me like I don't have permissions to mount the folder on the destination: `/mnt/my_vol` rather than the source (`//xxx.xx.com/<MY_FOLDER>`) but I can't explain why...

Comment: did you maange to solve this? i am having the same problem with my container

Comment: Hi @leeKing no I wasn’t able to unfortunately